# JAVA SCRIPT - ASSIGN DATA VALUES AUTOMATICALLY TO DATA BY COMMAS

Tags: java, javascript

i really need help on this

Lets says the input is parameter - 2,2,2,2

How can i assign the value for every parameter

1st parameter is 2 so the value assign will be 0 and 1.

I have an example of code but it is in java and i need to do it in JavaScript

```
    for(int i=0; i<args.length;i++)
    {
        if(args[i].equals("-i"))
        {
            String data_str= new String();

            //SPECIFY DATA VALUES

            if(i+1<args.length)
            {
                i++;
                System.out.println ("Parameter => "+args[i]);
                data_str=args[i};
            }

            //ASSIGN DATA VALUES AUTOMATICALLY TO DATA BY COMMAS

            StringTokenizer s = newStringTokenizer (data_str,",")

            //COUNT PARAMETER

            int p = data_str.replaceAll("[^,]","").length();
            p++;//AS AN ARRAY SIZE
            data= new int[p];
            int k = 0;
            while(s.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                data[k]=Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken());
                k++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your input string into array.

```
"2,2,2,2".split(",")
```

It will lead you to

```
["2", "2", "2", "2"]
```

Then you can do whatever you want with your array of args.

If you need integer value, just parse it

```
parseInt("2") == 2;
```